# Semicolon or colon in this sentence

Tags: punctuation, semicolons, colons

I want to put an semicolon in his sentence, but I am not sure it is right.

> Hi, SCM deployed this; it is ready for testing.

Also, could a colon be used in place of the semi-colon?

Comment: Please take a look at our [Contributor's Guide](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners) on meta. It has some very useful tips about text formatting, question titles, question details, and shared research.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a semicolon is appropriate there. That sentence is joining two independent clauses without using a conjunction. It could be rewritten as two sentences:

> SCM deployed this. It is ready for testing.

or as one sentence with a conjunction:

> SCM deployed this, and it is ready for testing.

When both of those are true, a semi-colon may be used.

The semi-colon stresses the independence of the two parts more than the version with *and*, but stresses their connection more than the version with two separate sentences.

By contrast, a colon may be used for several things, but not in the example.

A colon can be used for several purposes:

- To introduce a list of items;
- To introduce a quotation or a statement in direct dialog, which is or could be in quotation marks;
- To connect a phrase that is not a complete sentence and serves as an introduction with an independent clause that could stand as a separate sentance;
- To introduce an example.
- Between chapter and verse in a Bible citaion;
- Between hours and minutes when giving a tiem;
- Between title and subtitle of a work being cited;

Some people use colons to join independent clauses that are parallel in form. I do not favor this, but in any case it does not apply to the example.

Comment: Why can't/shouldn't you use a colon?

Comment: @GC_ I have expanded the answer with ways in which a colon can be used.